# How can i turn a card into its original position?

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to know how I can turn back to its original position BOTH cards that didn't match. 
If there is a match, there is an alert saying congrats, otherwise try again, but i want that two cards to return to its original position.
 The card images are not in here. Can someone help with this?
I want to know how I can turn back to its original position BOTH cards that didn't match. 
If there is a match, there is an alert saying congrats, otherwise try again, but i want that two cards to return to its original position.
 The card images are not in here. Can someone help with this?

```js
// HOW TO RESTART EVERYTHING WITH TIMEOUT 2s AFTER WINNING OR LOOSING?
//HOW TO BACKFLIP BOTH CARDS IF WRONG?

//GLOBAL VAR
const box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
var cards = [{
    name: 'queen',
    clase: 'diamonds',
    pic: 'images/queen-of-diamonds.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'queen',
    clase: 'hearts',
    pic: 'images/queen-of-hearts.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'king',
    clase: 'diamonds',
    pic: 'images/king-of-diamonds.png'
  },
  {
    name: 'king',
    clase: 'hearts',
    pic: 'images/king-of-hearts.png'
  }
];

function createBoard() {
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var photo = document.createElement('img');
    // console.log(foto);
    photo.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
    photo.setAttribute('data-id', i);
    box.appendChild(photo);
    photo.style.paddingLeft = '20px';
    photo.style.marginTop = '20px';
    photo.style.height = '40%';
    photo.style.width = '15%';
    photo.style.borderRadius = '3%';
    photo.addEventListener('click', function flipcard() {
      var cardId = this.getAttribute('data-id');
      console.log(cardId + ' is my card id');
      var myThis = this; // I want to export THIS cause i cannot access from the other function
      cardsInPlay.push(cards[cardId].name);
      this.setAttribute('src', cards[cardId].pic);
      // console.log(this);
      if (cardsInPlay.length === 2) {
        checkForMatch(myThis, cardId, photo);
      }
    });
  }
}
createBoard()
var cardsInPlay = [];
//2

function checkForMatch(myThis, cardId, photo) { // match cards dont turn back
  if (cardsInPlay[0] === cardsInPlay[1]) {
    alert('CONGRATS!!! YOU FOUND A MATCH');

  } else {
    alert('SORRY TRY AGAIN');
    myThis.setAttribute('src', 'images/back.png');
    console.log(myThis);

  }
}
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: white;
  width: 860px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  /*background-color: black;*/
  text-align: center;
  background-color: inherit;
}

body {
  background-color: #0caab6;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CARDS</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>PLAY GAME</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  <script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, your `cardsInPlay` array contains the `name`s of the cards clicked. If you use it to store references to the clicked `img` elements instead, you'll be able to access everything you need to check for matches and flip the cards back over without passing anything to `checkForMatch`. Make sure to empty the array after checking!

<sub>There's a lot that can be improved here. After you get it working, consider posting to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).</sub>

Comment: One more question, you see the mess i did haha. But WHY the myThis i stores to pass to another function, only prints the last card clicked and not both?